# Methods of visualizing joins

Tags: sql, join

Just wondering if anyone has any tricks (or tools) they use to visualize joins.  You know, you write the perfect query, hit run, and after it's been running for 20 minutes, you realize you've probably created a cartesian join.

I sometimes have difficulty visualizing what's going to happen when I add another join statement and wondered if folks have different techniques they use when trying to put together lots of joins.

Comment: Know your data, and know your joins - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @OMGPonies that's about the best answer to this I've thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always keep the end in mind.

1. Ascertain which are the columns you need
2. Try to figure out the minimum number of tables which will be needed to do it.
3. Write your FROM part with the table which will give max number of columns. eg FROM Teams T
4. Add each join one by one on a new line. Ensure whether you'll need OUTER, INNER, LEFT, RIGHT JOIN at each step.

Usually works for me. Keep in mind that it is *Structured* query language. Always break your query into logical lines and it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Every join combines two resultsets into one.  Each may be from a single database table or a temporary resultset which is the result of previous join(s) or of a subquery.
Always know the order that joins are processed, and, for each join, know the nature of the two temporary result sets that you are joining together.  Know what logical entity each row in that resultset represents, and what attributes in that resultset uniquely identify that entity.  If your join is intended to always join one row to one row, these key attributes are the ones you need to use (in join conditions) to implement the join.  If your join is intended to generate some kind of cartesian product, then it is critical to understand the above to understand how the join conditions (whatever they are) will affect the cardinality of the new joined resultset.

Try to be consistent in the use of outer join directions. I try to always use Left Joins when I need an outer join, as I "think" of each join as "joining" the new table (to the right) to whatever I have already joined together (on the left) of the Left Join statement...

Answer (score 0):

Run an explain plan.

These are always hierarchical trees (to do *this*, first I must do *that*). Many tools exist to make these plans into graphical trees, some in SQL browsers, (e.g, Oracle SQLDeveloper, whatever SQlServer's GUI client is called). If you don't have a tool, most plan text ouput includes a "depth" column, which you can use to indent the line.

What you want to look for is the *cost* of each row. (Note that for Oracle, though, higher costs can mean *less* time, if it allows Oracle to do a hash join rather than nested loops, *and* if the final result set has high cardinality (many, many rows).)

Answer (score 0):

I have never found a better tool than thinking it through and using my own mind.

If the query is so complicated that you cannot do that, you may want to use either CTE's, views, or some other carefully organized subqueries to break it into logical pieces so you can easily understand and visualize each piece even if you cannot manage the whole.

Also, if your concern is effeciency, then SQL Server Management Studio 2005 or later lets you get estimated query execution plans without actually executing the query.  This can give you very good ideas of where problems lie, if you are using MS SQL Server.