# Compare 2 fields in 2 tables and extract data

Tags: php, sql, mysql

How do i compare 2 fields in 2 tables, find a match and use it ?
example:

table1: data1(id_data1,name,address,phone,account)
table2: data2(id_data2,name2)

now in php:
if (name2.table2 has a matching name in name.table1) { give me the address,phone,account }

Comment: Please make a real life example.

Comment: this is my real life example, exactly as i have (table1, table2)

Comment: You should call your tables something more descriptive - table1 and table2 are bad choices!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use [JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT data FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
```

There are different types of JOINs, which one to use will depend on what you need.
Here's a question on [visualizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375587/methods-of-visualizing-joins/) the different types of JOINs.

*EDIT*: I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT table1.name, phone, other_info_here 
FROM table1 AS t1 RIGHT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.name=t2.name 
WHERE t1.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You can do a JOIN on any field, it doesn't have to be id.

Comment: DOESN'T WORKS:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name2")
because it always gets the address,phone,account of the last record id